# Autogenerate constructor code in Swift

Tags: swift

I find myself spending a lot of time writing boilerplate constructors code like the following. Is there a way to make XCode generate this/some way to make this process faster?

```
public class T {
  let t1: T1
  let t2: T2
  let t3: T3

  public init(t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3) {
    self.t1 = t1
    self.t2 = t2
    self.t3 = t3
  }
```

Comment: If appropriate, use a `struct` instead of a `class` and such an `init` method is provided by default.

Comment: Found this github repo, may it helps.

Sorry for giving link only :)

https://github.com/rjoudrey/swift-init-generator

Comment: It works out of the box without any additional repo's with my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54378722/7715250

Answer (score 2):

[Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) is the great tool for that.

Here is template you can use (for sourcery version > 0.10):

```
{% for type in types.structs %}
{% if type|annotated:"AutoInit" %}
{% set spacing %}{% if type.parentName %}    {% endif %}{% endset %}
{% map type.storedVariables into parameters using var %}{{ var.name }}: {{ var.typeName }}{% endmap %}
// sourcery:inline:auto:{{ type.name }}.AutoInit
{{spacing}}    {{ type.accessLevel }} init({{ parameters|join:", " }}) { // swiftlint:disable:this line_length
{{spacing}}        {% for variable in type.storedVariables %}
{{spacing}}        self.{{ variable.name }} = {{ variable.name }}
{{spacing}}        {% endfor %}
{{spacing}}    }
// sourcery:end
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I got template from this [AutoInit](https://code-craftsman.fr/2017/09/24/AutoInit/) article